# Change brackground in Twilio Video for React Native and React in iOS browsers

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, twilio, twilio-video

I've recently developed video calls with twilio video in our React app. I've used twilio/video-processor too changing video background to white screen. But it's only working in chrome desktop browsers and mostly on Android.
In iOS doesn't work (specified in documentation) but it's a highly requirement.

Now we've developing React Native apps for both Android and iOS and here are my questions.

There's a way having a white background video in iOS web browsers? Maybe with TensorFlow.js and WebRTC ? or it's only working in desktop?

There's a way to change background for twilio video in React Native?